# Caching functions in python

Tags: python, function, caching

Are there any built in ways in python 3 to cache functions that have no side effects? Or maybe it's already done automatically? If so, are there any ways to save cache when program is closed?

Comment: Try looking into functools lru_cache decorator

Comment: Here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html

Comment: made my code hundreds times faster :)

Comment: Very good, glad I could help :)